# How do C++ programmers get started with game macros/bots?

Tags: macros, game-development, bots

I'd like to see C++ in action by macroing trigger actions in closed-source video games.  For example, there's a game on every Windows machine called Space Pinball.  I would like to macro in some key-bound targeting by figuring out the physics of the ball and the force of the flippers.  Another game that would be fun to play would be something like Final Fantasy VII.  I have some simple math that I do in my head as I play FFVII on an emulator on my machine.  I usually play in the underground submarine to level up, and I want to have my characters burn the appropriate spells or items based on their hp and what-have-you.  I also want to include an autobuy function.  Similarly, getting the Gold Chocobo takes forever.  I wonder if I could automate this as a coding project....

The two main parts of macroing/botting, I imagine, would be:
A) Receiving info from the games, and
B) Sending latency-free keystrokes to the games.

I anticipate many other troubles, of course.

Now, someone told me a good way to get started would be to build my own text-only versions of the games and try to mess around with the code there to get everything right.  Since I'm starting to get pretty good at that, I think I'm ready to tackle the barriers I've listed above.  How can I start to get to the point where I can macro games? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that what you're asking for is not as easy as you might think. Usually games with bots/macros are open source, or at least some documentation/APIs are available (for example Half-Life 1 had a lot of mods and bots because it had an SDK). If nothing like this is available, you have no other way than reverse engineer the game and try to figure out how it does work (debugging for example, I recommend [OllyDebugger](http://www.ollydbg.de/)). This is no easy stuff if you're not comfortable with programming, and even so RE takes time and experience.

Comment: m0skit0, I can imagine that would take a lot of time.  Still, I've seen many macroing programs that rely on font recognition or initiation of mp3 files.  Using a program to read local memory, I could surely find the values that represent things like player health, at the very least?  But recognizing an event like, say, a monster casting a spell in FF VII, would be unheard of for me.  I don't know what to do after I read something from memory, though, to macro against the value.

Comment: ...because that would require inputting the read value into the program and sending keystrokes based on the interpreted meaning of the values.

Comment: Well getting values from memory is not a hard thing. Just search memory for life values and watch them to see which one/s change when you drink a health potion, for example. The hardest thing definitely are actions. For that you definitely need to debug to see what function/s are called to do a given action. Then you could call those functions through your macro, but for this you need to know what are the meanings of parameters passed to the function/s (at least useful parameters). Also keep in mind all this will most likely get you kicked out of MMO game servers.

Comment: m0skit0, How do you get target info for the health?  At least that would give me a start.  If I were to compare FF VII enemy healths to local healths, I could at least have my characters flee by initiating a keystroke.  That would be cool because I would be able to say, "Hey!  I did something!"  Does discovery of target info become easier when you know that it is the target's hp changing?

Comment: Well, there is no universal/standard method (that's the "engineering" part on "reverse engineering"). It depends on how the game handles it internally. Most likely it's the same number you see on the screen. The easiest way IMHO is watching which values are changing on memory when you're on a battle (use a debugger as I said above). From those values, you should be able to recognize easily which ones are the health. Also for FFVII enemy's health will most likely not be a fixed memory address but rather a dynamic one...

Comment: ...So your best bet is to track the function (code) that actually does that, or the code that allocates memory for the ennemies (as I said, there's no universal method). I hope you have some programming knowledge, specially x86 assembly, otherwise this is gonna be quite steepy...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1615/discussion-between-m0skit0-and-wolfpack08)